# Password Complexity in 19.10

Tags: password, 19.10

Our last Windows laptop crashed and Covid-19 is requiring us to support Remote Learning.  I rebuilt the laptop with 19.10, and I am trying to setup an account for my 6 year old.  She is not yet proficient at typing, or anything else computer related.  I need to shorten her password to something she will remember.  Her school password is three letters and two numbers.  But this failed the password complexity check in 19.10

I updated /etc/pad.d.common-password by removing **obscure** and replacing it with **minlen=6** but that did not work.

```
#password   [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so minlen=6 sha512
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
password    required            pam_permit.so
password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

Is there someplace else where I can control the complexity rule?

Comment: Have you tried creating the account with a password that meets the rules, then using your account (elevating privileges with `sudo` of course) changing the password to what she wants/knows? (ie. using `passwd` to change password and specifying her account name so it's not changing your password).   It'd be what I'd do (not changing configs).

Comment: Perfect.  That worked.  Thank you.

Comment: If you want, you can write your own answer (credit me if you wish), and give it time (site rules require you to allow others to provide answers), then you can accept your answer gaining you some cred/rep on this site :)